# Http error code if backend db call does not result any result

Tags: api, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am building an API in AWS API gateway that has a get method (with id as query param) making a call  to lambda function that in turn gets data from dynamodb.

If an id that is passed does not exist in dynamodb, the dynamodb  returns an empty json. I can check the length of json to determine that the result set is empty. And I can return an message that the id was not found.

Now the Get, lambda function and dynamodb GetItem have all succeed. Just that there's no data returned.

Should the Get method response code be 200 or some other 4xx code to indicate that the input was not correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some room for interpretation especially when people sometimes design their APIs to use URL path queries like `http://example.com/find/someID`. In this case `someID` can be considered a resource on the server that was not found and returning 404 makes some sense. In your case, assuming your URLs look like `http://example.com/find?query=someID`, I think a 404 is inappropriate. It is difficult to distinguish between a resource that was legitimately not found a correct resource, `/find`, but with a query that has no results. Returning `200` in this case makes more sense to me because the request was not really an error.

Without knowing how your API is being consumed, it's hard to say for certain, but I suspect it will be easier on the user if you distinguish between errors and zero results. Imagine, for example, using something like Google and getting a 404 if you searched for something it couldn't find.

The most important thing, or course, is to document it well and be consistent.

Comment: That's very well put. Your example with http://example.com/find?query=someID is how my URL looks. The google search returning 404 drives the point home. Thank you.